# Placing php variables into mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

If you don't want to get a full summary of what I'm trying to do skip to (Problem starts here)

I'm setting up my new site and came across a problem.

What I'm basically trying to do is to assign ads to specific countries. So for example if your from the UK you would be shown ads that we have in our UK inventory.

So I gathered some data from Google on how to detect a user's country based on their IP.
I've made a function which does this perfectly.

```
$ip_address= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function ip_location($ip){
    $parts = explode('.', $ip);
    $numeric_ip = $parts[3] + (256 * $parts[2]) + (256 * 256 * $parts[1]) + (256 * 256 * 256 * $parts[0]);

    $sql = "SELECT country FROM iptocountry WHERE lower_bound <= $numeric_ip AND upper_bound >= $numeric_ip LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $country = mysql_result($result, 0);
    return $country;
}

$country = ip_location($ip_address);
echo $country; // Always echos the correct country
```

**(Problem Starts here)**

So this function works fine. After making this function I created a MYSQL query which uses the data from that function to select an ad to show a user.

Here is where the problem starts.

When I type this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `nuevo__htmlad` WHERE `country` = 'united kingdom' AND `active` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

using `country = 'united kingdom'` it works fine but when I put `country = '$country'`

Nothing works it never displays an ad.

Can anyone help me understand why this query doesn't work when I place the PHP variable inside it. This actually is the first time something this simple has troubled me so much.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by printing your query `echo $sql;` and show us the result.

Comment: What @MathieuImbert said, but to clarify, show us what `echo $sql` shows in both the hard-coded country and the variable use.

Comment: You could simply do `INSERT .... VALUES (INET_ATON('$ip'))` and save yourself the PHP-side math. That WILL blow up on a 32bit php install at some point.

Comment: @MarcB This method is already blowing up with IPV6 addresses.

Comment: Please consider using bind variables.  Also, geolocating by IP address is a notoriously hard problem to do, as you say, 'perfectly.'

Comment: Also you should consider using mod_geoip if you can, it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: echo $sql; give this result SELECT * FROM `nuevo__htmlad` WHERE `country` = 'United Kingdom ' AND `active` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: You have a space after your country name. Is that a typo?

Comment: http://php.net/ip2long ?

Comment: @MathieuImbert sharp eyes. I'll bet the extra space is what's messing up the matching.

Comment: @MathieuImbert  substr_replace ($country , '' , -1); Made it work... Thanks for your sharp eye

Comment: @GlodyZangu Glad I could help, I'll write a post to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking a few questions in the comments, it turned out that the `$country` variable contained and additional empty space.

OP fixed it using `substr_replace ($country , '' , -1)`. I would personaly choose `trim()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `nuevo__htmlad` WHERE `country` = '".trim($country)."' AND `active` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: No. You win a downvote for giving an example without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 1):

I avoid this by using a PDO driver for working with databases. This allows me to use parameters and makes it easy to reuse sql statements. Check out [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

All of the code in the answers provided here contains SQL Injection vulnerabilities. You MUST escape the user input.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: The [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) site has a great introduction.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql= "SELECT *  FROM nuevo__htmlad WHERE country='$country' AND active=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

or this try this one also

```
$sql= "SELECT *  FROM nuevo__htmlad WHERE country='$country' AND active=1 LIMIT 1 ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Comment: You win a downvote for giving an example without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: That in appropriate. I just provided a specific answer to a specific question.

Comment: While that's technically correct, answers like these promote extremely dangerous habits.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:
I always use this style since country is a string

```
$sql= "SELECT *  FROM nuevo__htmlad WHERE country='".$country."' AND active=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Wrong. You win a downvote for giving an example without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).